# Button "On click" animation laggy in mobile browsers/views

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-animations, tailwind-css

I am building a UI in Nuxtjs and animating a button with TailwindCSS.
Everything is going smoothly except this button animation seems to lag behind on mobile views.
This is an issue since the button is designed to be rapidly clicked, which on mobile, makes the animation not run at all most of the time.
I am using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> and tried various` touch-action` properties in CSS.

This is the code for the button component

```
<template>
  <button
    class="p-1 bg-gray-800 ring-2 ring-gray-800 ring-offset-4 rounded-full shadow-md text-gray-200 transition-all transform linear duration-75 active:text-gray-100 active:shadow active:scale-95 hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-lg"
    :class="[fullColor]"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out these links.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/
https://www.urbaninsight.com/article/improving-html5-app-performance-gpu-accelerated-css-transitions

TLDR: try setting transform: translateX(0);

I believe this will force the element to be rendered using the GPU which might make the animation smoother. Not 100% sure, but those articles should help.

Comment: Hmm, so far no luck. Tailwind even has a `transform-gpu` class but no change.